# I can not get my loop to end

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a higher or lower game in python but can't get my loop to end. it just keeps going. My code looks like this

```
a = 0
def ask(b, d, p):
    global a
    while a < d:
        global question
        question = int(input())
        if question < b:
            print"bigger"
        elif question > b:
            print"smaller"
        else:
            print p
            break
        del question
        a += 1
        if  d1 == p1:
            print "wow. you lost. shame on you."
            time.sleep(3)
            quit()
```

if anybody can tell me what I did wrong that would be great.

Comment: What is the rest of the program?  How is `ask` called?

Comment: Without knowing whether `d` is really large number, or whether `a` (being global) gets set to some really large negative number, it's hard to tell. (In fact, why not put `a` inside the function: no need to make it global.)

Comment: In python 2.x, `raw_input` is used instead of `input` to get text. `input` will evaluate the expression. That's good in a way because "1" is automatically converted to an int for you and in fact you could enter things like `2**5`, but you could also enter wrong values such as `[1,2,3]` or other dubious things.

Comment: Since `d1` and `p1` are undefined, the code as printed here should raise a NameError if execution gets that far.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the rest of the code is here is what I can offer.

In the code provided you have `d1 == p1` but they are never called or assigned in that area so they will never change. Therefore your loop can never progress because they variables inside it do not control it.

edit: I'm sorry you are correct @Evert. If `a` ever goes above what `d` is then it should end. So the loop should end eventually, but likely not when intended should they get it right. Should be `if question == answer`.

Comment: There's still `while a < d` and `a += 1` before that. But yes, the question is too vague on the necessary details.